# Unable to check for empty textfields in IOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to check for empty fields in the login page of IOS app using swift story board. The code is pasted below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
 if (firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!{
        userMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required")
        return
    }
```

I am getting the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Unrelated directly to the issue but there is better way to check for *has text*: The `hasText` property. However it does not fix a crash at another place in case the outlet is not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that all the outlets are connected properly.

**Problem**

The possible cause of the crash can be..

- The result of `firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty` may be null and you have used `!` to unwrap so it get crashed
- Or may possible that the `IBOutlet` is not connected to view controller in storyboard.

**Solution**

You can user `if-let` like below...

```
let fanme = firstNameTextField.text ?? ""
let lname = lastNameTextField.text ?? ""
let email = emailTextField.text ?? ""
let password = passwordTextField.text ?? ""

if fname.isEmpty || lname.isEmpty || email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
    userMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required")
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. There was connection issue. Deleted the initialisers and added them again.

Comment: the radio button kind of thing beside the '@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField' keeps getting unchecked. How do I connect it again without deleting and adding it again?

Comment: I think, it should not get the automatic uncheck for the radio button beside `@IBOutlet`. Once you connected it will not automatically unchecked. Yes, it may take some time to load but as far as I knot it will not unchecked automatically

Comment: it keeps getting unchecked for me. I am new to this and maybe I might be doing something wrong. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must unwrap your variable and after check if tf are empty:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
```

Now  write the func to check:

```
@objc func chekTfIsEmpty () {
    guard let firstTF = firstNameTextField.text else { return } // unwrapped
    guard let lastNameTF = lastNameTextField.text else { return } // unwrapped
    guard let emailTF = emailTextField.text else { return } // unwrapped
    guard let passTF = passwordTextField.text else { return } // unwrapped
    
    if firstTF.isEmpty ||
        lastNameTF.isEmpty ||
        emailTF.isEmpty ||
        passTF.isEmpty {
        userMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required") 
        return
    } else {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

after that call the this function with your login button...